# Lodash _.omitBy and _.isEmpty - removing an empty array, but leaving booleans and integers

Tags: javascript, lodash

I've got an object in a shape like this:

```
const objectExample = {
  id: 2132131,
  title: 'Some title',
  tags: [],
  isFree: true,
}
```

What I want to achieve is removing properties with an empty array (in this case `tags`). I've firstly tried

```
_.omitBy(objectExample, _.isEmpty)
```

but according to Lodash documentation `isEmpty` return true also for integers and booleans, so my `id` and `isFree` are also filtered out, which is not a desired behaviour.

I've tried to mix it up with `_.isArray`, but it still returns the same:

```
_.omitBy(transformedSession, _.isArray && _.isEmpty)
```

It seems like only takes into account the first condition. Can I mix them somehow?

Is there a simple, lodash way to remove properties when an array is empty, but leave integers and booleans? Wrapping integers with `String()` would be enough for me, but there are also booleans and I'm stuck.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `_.omitBy(transformedSession, _.isArray && _.isEmpty)` the expression `_.isArray && _.isEmpty` is evaluated to `_.isEmpty` since `_.isArray` is a function (a truthy value). So it's identical to just writing `_.omitBy(objectExample, _.isEmpty)`.

Use an arrow function and test if the value is an empty array:

```js
const { omitBy, isArray, isEmpty } = _

const objectExample = {
  id: 2132131,
  title: 'Some title',
  tags: [],
  isFree: true,
}

const result = omitBy(objectExample, 
  v => isArray(v) && isEmpty(v)
)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: Wow awesome!! So simple and obvious, but yet I didn't think about that, I was so stuck in my way of thinking about the problem I didn't see it broader. Thank you very much!